# SymPy: Using vector_integrate for flux integrals, what way is the direction of the normal vector?

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

I'm calculating the flux of vector v = [2xz, (x+2), y(z^2 - 3)] through the top five sides (ie all sides excluding the bottom) of the cube (x,0,2), (y,0,2), (z,0,2). See attached picture for visual.

I'm using sympy to do this, specifically the vector_integrate and ParametricRegion functions from sympy.vector:

```
   import sympy as smp
   import sympy.vector as smpv

   R = smpv.CoordSys3D('R')
   x,y,z = smp.symbols('x,y,z')
   x,y,z = R.x,R.y,R.z

   v = (2*x*z)*R.i + (x + 2)*R.j + y*(z**2 - 3)*R.k
   s_1 = smpv.ParametricRegion((2,y,z),(y,0,2),(z,0,2))
   s_2 = smpv.ParametricRegion((0,y,z),(y,0,2),(z,0,2))
   s_3 = smpv.ParametricRegion((x,2,z),(x,0,2),(z,0,2))
   s_4 = smpv.ParametricRegion((x,0,z),(x,0,2),(z,0,2))
   s_5 = smpv.ParametricRegion((x,y,2),(x,0,2),(y,0,2))
```

Using `sympy.vector.vector_integrate` of v on side 3:

```
smpv.vector_integrate(v,s_3)
```

You get a result of -12. The answer *should* be positive 12, though it depends on the direction one chooses as the proper normal vector -- in this case, it can be either the positive or negative y-direction. It seems to be choosing the negative y-direction -- integrating side 4 also brings a result of -12 -- but it seems to choose the postive x-direction and positive z-direction for sides 1 and 5, respectively.

Is there a way to formally specify the desired normal vector? Or is there a way to consistently know which side *it* chooses, so that I can at least predict it and change signs manually? Am I making some other mistake?

Problem Solution:
[image]

Problem Diagram:
[image]

Comment: I have found that if I change the parametrization of side 3 to `s_3 = smpv.ParametricRegion((x,2,z),(z,0,2),(x,0,2))`, it gives positive 12 when doing `smpv.vector_integrate(v,s_3)`. I *believe* that it determines the normal vector based on the order of parametrization using the RHR.  Thus, by ordering z first, it's z_hat x x_hat, = +y_hat